# Printing List to DOM from array in Local Storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html

I feel like I am very close on this.

Have a checklist which I'm pushing to an array, and setting to local storage. I want to reprint the list from local storage when the browser is re-instantiated

```
<script>

    localStorage.clear();

    var Array_ToDoList = [];
    var toDoCount = 0;

    $("#add-to-do").on("click", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var toDoTask = $("#to-do").val().trim();

      Array_ToDoList.push(toDoTask)
      localStorage.setItem("STR_Tasks", JSON.stringify(Array_ToDoList))

      console.log(Array_ToDoList);

      var toDoItem = $("<p>");
      toDoItem.attr("id", "item-" + toDoCount);
      toDoItem.append(" " + toDoTask);

      var toDoClose = $("<button>");
      toDoClose.attr("data-to-do", toDoCount);
      toDoClose.addClass("checkbox");
      toDoClose.append("✓");

      toDoItem = toDoItem.prepend(toDoClose);
      $("#to-dos").append(toDoItem);
      $("#to-do").val("");
      toDoCount++;
    });

    $(document.body).on("click", ".checkbox", function() {
      var toDoNumber = $(this).attr("data-to-do");
      $("#item-" + toDoNumber).remove();
      Array_ToDoList.splice(toDoNumber, 1);
      console.log(Array_ToDoList);
      localStorage.setItem("STR_Tasks", JSON.stringify(Array_ToDoList))
    });


    var StoredToDos = Array_ToDoList.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < StoredToDos; i++) {
    $("#to-dos").append(localStorage.getitem(STR_Tasks[i]));    
    }

  </script>
```

I know that I have to read the array and reprint, it may be something to with de-stringifying what I have in store.

Comment: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('STR_Tasks')).forEach(function(element) {//implementation});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to my understanding on the literally code:

1. it's 'localStorage.getItem' not 'getitem'
2. the key store in localStorage was "STR_Tasks", it's just string, not iterable type
3. i think you should push the object 'todoItem' into 'Array_ToDoList', then 'JSON.stringify' it then storge into the localStorage

at last, you can do like this:

```
var tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("STR_Tasks"));
for (var i = 0; i < StoredToDos; i++) {
    $("#to-dos").append(tasks[i]);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first line of the script you clear all the keys in the local storage so you can not use the previous list instead replace localStorage.clear() with :

```
var Array_ToDoList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('STR_Tasks') || '[]');
```

This will make your script use the currently saved STR_Tasks.

Comment: This is great! I can now use the parse string again to "render" the listed items again in the browser.

Comment: Happy to help :)